# unhandled exception java.net.malformedurlexception

Tags: java, url

How come this code is giving me a `unhandled exception java.net.malformedurlexception` in java ?

```
String u = "http://webapi.com/demo.zip";
URL url = new URL(u);
```

Can someone tell me how to fix?

Comment: just handle the exception using a try catch block or declare it in the throws clause so that the caller is forced to handle it

Comment: Put simply, handle the exception: catch it in a try/catch block, or add `throws malformedurlexception` to the containing method signature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to handle the posible exception.

Try with this:

```
    try {
        String u = "http://webapi.com/demo.zip";
        URL url = new URL(u);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a try catch statement to handle exceptions:

```
String u = "http://webapi.com/demo.zip";
try {
    URL url = new URL(u);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    //do whatever you want to do if you get the exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.net.malformedurlexception
```

It means that no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed or your URL is not confirmed the spec or missing a component
I think this will help you to understand URL

> https://url.spec.whatwg.org/